# Date picker disable date not working with given date array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using below date picker to my project
[date-picker plugin](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

I am trying to add disable date to my calendar. This approached working well. disabled date is correctly disabled.

```
var mydisabledDates = ['2020-12-25','2020-12-26'];

    $("#datepicker_projectStartDate").datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
    datesDisabled:mydisabledDates  
});
```

but actual date set come as a date array. Its like below

```
var mydisabledDates = [2020-12-25 12:00,2020-12-26 12:00];
```

This not working with the function. how I convert this array, correctly

[real object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OskBA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your image of real object you are having string which represents the array. So your mydisabledDates will be like below

```
var mydisabledDates = "[2020-12-25 12:00, 2020-12-26 12:00]";
```

You need to convert that `string` into array as below. Replace `[` & `]` with empty string `""`. Then split string with `,` and convert that string into `Date` object. As below you will get value in new object `disabledDates`. Use this object in `datesDisabled: disabledDates`.

Try complete code as below.

```js
var mydisabledDates = "[2020-12-25 12:00, 2020-12-26 12:00]";
var disabledDates = mydisabledDates.replace("[", "")
                      .replace("]", "")
                      .split(',')
                      .map(d => new Date(d.trim()));

$("#datepicker_projectStartDate").datepicker({
  format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
  daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
  datesDisabled: disabledDates // <- Use new object
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<div class="input-group date">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker_projectStartDate">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. this is working well

Answer (score 1):

for changing ['2020-12-25 12:00','2020-12-26 12:00'] to ['2020-12-25','2020-12-26']
try

```
    var mydisabledDates = ['2020-12-25 12:00','2020-12-26 12:00'];
    var disabledDates =[]; 
    mydisabledDates.forEach(d=>disabledDates.push(d.slice(0,9)));

    $("#datepicker_projectStartDate").datepicker({
         format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
         daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
         datesDisabled:disabledDates  
     });
```

Comment: error occurred  Project:469 Uncaught TypeError: mydisabledDates.forEach is not a function

Comment: can you console.log the value of mydisabledDates ? is it an array?

Comment: console.log did not work. because error in forEach

Comment: console.log before forEach

Comment: in my array there are no quotes, its date array like 
[2020-12-25 12:00,2020-12-26 12:00] no double quotes

Comment: @Kumara That's not possible to have array like `[2020-12-25 12:00,2020-12-26 12:00]`. It could be either `string` with double/single quote or it might be an `object`s inside `array`. Please log your `mydisabledDates` object as `console.log(mydisabledDates)` and share the result.

Comment: if it is an array of dates @lamtacvu 's answer should work

Comment: I added real object format from image.. can u check..

Comment: I assigned that values from this line
 var mydisabledDates = $("#txtHolidayListEnd").val()

Comment: it is of type string, that's why you are getting those errors. How are you setting the value of txtHolidayListEnd?

Comment: its come from backend side.. its not with me.. how ever i need to do this from my side.. is it possible

Comment: the backend can't set the value of the textbox, it has to be done on the frontend.  do you set the value for txtHolidayListEnd?

Comment: You can change '[[2020-12-25 12:00,2020-12-26 12:00]' into an array

Answer (score 0):

You need a convert your array's element type to correct format:

```
function convertDate(datetime){
    return datetime.getFullYear()+"-"+(datetime.getMonth() + 1)+"-"+datetime.getDate();
}

var mydisabledDates = ['2020-12-25 12:00', '2020-12-26 12:00'];
mydisabledDates  = mydisabledDates.map(disabledDate=> convertDate(new Date(Date.parse(disabledDate) ) ));

$("#datepicker_projectStartDate").datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
    datesDisabled:mydisabledDates  
});
```

Comment: Project:474 Uncaught TypeError: mydisabledDates.map is not a function

Comment: in my array there are no quotes, its date array like [2020-12-25 12:00,2020-12-26 12:00] no double quotes

Comment: Project:474 Uncaught TypeError: mydisabledDates.map is not a function is ann error you will get if mydisabledDates is not an array

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that shows how to convert your data to desired format

```js
   let data = '[2020-12-25 12:00,2020-12-26 12:00]'
   data = data.slice(1,data.length-1); // get rid of the brackets
   
  var mydisabledDates = data.split(','); // create a new array of strings from the data string

    mydisabledDates = mydisabledDates.map(d=>d.slice(0,10));

   console.log( mydisabledDates)
```